# Rails f.select Save Id an Name at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes

I have a form with the f.select option. I want to add the Company ID and the Company Name when the company name is selected from the options. Is it possible to add multiple attributes in the f.select line of code? This is how my code looks:

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label 'Client' %>
 <%= f.select :client_id, Client.all.collect { |c| [ c.companyName, c.id ] } %>
```

I want to also assign the companyName to my :companyName attribute, but the id is the only thing that is being saved right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use associations for this. You should have 2 models as below.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :clients
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :company
end
```

Your should use variable instead in views for rendering all clients list with this

```
<%= f.select :client_id, @clients.collect { |client| [ client.name, client.id] } %>
```

Controller:

```
@clients = Client.all
```

On Submit the `client_id` will be passed to controller. You can then find the company associated with the client and other logic.

```
client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
company = client.company
# etc ..
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action where your form submits you can write before saving or updating record.

```
params[:your_object][:companyName]=Client.find_by(id: params[:your_object][:client_id]).companyName
```

Remember to a add `params[:your_object][:companyName]` to your strong params. e.g.

```
params.require(:your_object).permit(:client_id, ... , :companyName)
```

Before anything be sure your `client_id` is in same object and permitted and apply same to `companyName` attribute

Hope This Helps